# .htaccess SEO friendly URLs not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

I have a question. I have spent the last 2 hours searching on the forums and I have not yet found an answer why my htaccess configuration is not working properly.

Here is my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.myserver.com/$1 [R]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443
RewriteRule ^block/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ block.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443
RewriteRule ^tx/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ tx.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443
RewriteRule ^address/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ address.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443
RewriteRule ^block/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ block.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443
RewriteRule ^tx/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ tx.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443
RewriteRule ^address/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ address.php?id=$1 [L]
```

The RewriteEngine works correctly, I can confirm when launching http:...myserver.com it gets redirected to https:...myserver.com.

However my SEO friendly URLS just don't work.
When launching https://myserver.com/block/12345 i only get an error message in my error.log:

```
[Tue Jan 07 22:08:07 2014] [error] [client 77.186.33.111] File does not exist: /var/www/block
```

So obviously it did not rewrite anything.

I would appreciate any help, I must be doing something substantially wrong, but for gods sake I cannot figure out myself.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're getting 404 because `RewriteRule` expects a trailing slash but your URI doesn't have one.

Replace your code with this and try again:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.myserver.com/$1 [R,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?id=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately also just the https redirection works. For the rest, the same error

`[Wed Jan 08 21:23:57 2014] [error] [client 77.12.44.45] File does not exist: /var/www/block, referer: https://xxxxxx.com/monitor.php`

Comment: I made an edit, can you try it now. I believe you are testing with `https://myserver.com/block/12345` URL.